# Отправка данных ajax с формы

Tags: php, ajax

Задача такая - я отображаю средствами PHP таблицу, затем при помощи AJAX туда по ИД добавляю данные. Затем мне это нужно отправить при клике на кнопку в PHPexcel. Что сделано - внутри ячеек стоит input readonly. Меня это коробит. Можно конечно сделать инпуты невидимыми, но опять же дублирование. Кто как выходил из такой ситуации?

получается такой вот ужс

```
<td>
<div id="37_2015-09-1_1_2" align="center">126.365</div>
<input id="t_37_2015-09-1_1_2" class="span2" type="text" name="C3" readonly="readonly">
</td>
```

получается для отображения я в див пишу значение, а для отправки аяксом еще и в инпут

Comment: Дублирование чего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например повесить на ячейку обработчик события onclick

```
<td onclick="proccessData('c3')">
     123.365
</td>
```

И уже в функции processData(id) отправлять аякс запрос.

Comment: можно более развернутый ответ?